# jscroll changing body-height?

Tags: height, scrollbar, footer, document-body

I decided to use [jscroll](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) on my upcoming website, but here's the problem I run into:

I made a rather sticky footer, that always stays at the end of the content, unless the content is not enough to fill the browser window. In that case it just stays at the bottom.
This is currently achieved through the following CSS (as described [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)):

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper1{
    min-height: 100%;
        width: 1250px;

}   

#content{
    overflow:auto;    
    padding: 0 0 30 0;
}

#footer {
    height:30px;
    width: 1250px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

With the HTML-structure being something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper1">
        <div id="content"> ... </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I apply jscroll to the body via `class="scroll-pane"` so that the browser scrollbar is replaced, the footer does NOT stay at the bottom of the page anymore, when there is not enough content to fill the browser window.

It seems like the `height:100%` rule is changed to `auto`. How could I prevent this?